# Symfony2 moving to demo bundle over to production

Tags: php, symfony

I am going thorough the [quick start](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html) for Symfony 2 and I'm getting quite confused. I have the following directory structure after unpacking Symfony2 (As in the documentation):

```
/var/www/ <- web root directory
    Symfony/ <- unpacked archive
        app/
            cache/
            config/
            logs/
            Resources/
        bin/
        src/
            Acme/
                DemoBundle/
                    Controller/
                    Resources/
                    ...
        vendor/
            symfony/
            doctrine/
            ...
        web/
            app.php
            ...
```

I've got the demo working at `<host>/Symfony2/web/app_dev.php/demo/welcome/James`. So far so good.

I know I can't use apache's `mod_rewrite` with `app_dev.php` so I was wondering if someone could give me a step by step to:

- **Moving the `DemoBundle` over to using `app.php`** (because `<host>/Symfony2/web/app.php/demo/hello/James` is not working. It's throwing up a Symfony error. I swear I haven't touched a thing. I'm at the bottom of the [first page of the tutorial](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_big_picture.html))
- **Keeping the development toolbar when using `app.php`** (do I just cut `web_profiler:` from `config/config_dev.yml`?)
- **Setting up Symfony2 outside of the web route** *(best thing for security I presume?!?)* (Should I have to have a soft link `/var/www/index.php` pointing to `/home/<name>/Symfony2/web/app.php`?)
- **Now I'm on the production version will I be able to go to `<host>/demo/welcome/James`, if not, why not?** (I have apache's `mod_rewrite` installed) *(I'd really like to get this bit working)*

*(I had the same problem learning django, just to much information to absorb at first.)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The demo is not meant to be run in production. However, if you wish to do so for learning purposes, simply move the routes `_demo` and `_demo_secured` from `app/config/routing_dev.yml` to `app/config/routing.yml`.
- Using the web profiler in production is again not sensible. Site visitors must not get access to such information. This is the reason why there are two separate front controllers (`app.php` and `app_dev.php`). They've both set up for different purposes.
- The best practice in setting up the web server would be to have the web root point to `./web`.

Comment: just realised after `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod --no-debug` I have to `chown -R www-data:www-data app/cache`. Now I can see the page on both `app_dev.php` and `app.php`